# Inheritance Type Joined JPA - query for property in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having trouble getting my server to start because it's complaining an inherited property is not found in the query.

For discussion purposes, I've set up a class hierarchy like this:

```
BaseContent
==============
id
createUser

Category
===============
id
otherProperties
```

I've declared the types like so:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "base_content")
public class BaseContent  {
...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "base_content_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class Category extends BaseContent{
}
```

Note that the relevant properties all have getter/setters etc.

I'm using Spring Data/JPA, and my server and Intellij both complain that the inherited property `createUser` (amongst others) can't be found for this query:

```
@Query("select c from Category c " +
            "left join fetch c.createUser " +
            "left join fetch c.lastUpdateUser " +
            "left join fetch c.galleries g " +
            "left join fetch g.media " +
            "left join fetch c.parentRelationship pr " +
            "left join fetch c.productCategoryRelationships pcr " +
            "left join fetch pcr.child " +
            "left join fetch c.appliedLayouts l " +
            "left join fetch pr.parent " +
            "where c.id = ?1")
    public Category findById(Long categoryId);
```

My question is, since I'm trying to move it to an inheritance model (joined), how do I reference the inherited property in an annotated query?

(note the property is private visibility with public getter/setter in BaseContent)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ah woops, I forgot the `@Entity` annotation on the superclass...

works now.